# Apple Watch, WatchKit Extension and main application

Tags: ios, program-entry-point, watchkit

There is main application with logic and we extend app to Apple Watch.

After adding target xCode creates 2 more applications: extension with code and watch kit application.

Question: How code from extension can reuse logic of ready and already made main iOS app? How extension app can communicate with main App and send commands.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Please be more specific with questions.  As per the documentation, you will have a main app that runs on the phone, an app extension that runs on the phone, and a watchkit bundle which are resources shuttled over to the watch for display on the watch.  None of your code actually runs on the watch.  You are just providing a resource bundle and data to the watch.

Comment: You can use App Groups or the https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To communicate to the containing iPhone app you can use

```
(BOOL)openParentApplication:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                        reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo,
                                        NSError *error))reply
```

In your `WKInterfaceController`

From the Apple Docs

> Use this method to communicate with your containing iOS app. Calling
>   the method causes iOS to launch the app in the background (as needed)
>   and call the `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply`: method
>   of its app delegate. That method has the following signature:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
```

> The app delegate receives the dictionary you pass into the userInfo
>   parameter and uses it to process whatever request you made. If it
>   provides a reply, WatchKit executes the block you provided in the
>   reply parameter of this method.

Comment: For a code example on how to use the background mode, which ensures that the main app has time to send its reply, refer to "Calling parent application from Watch app" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000274/calling-parent-application-from-watch-app/30000323#30000323)

Answer (score 4):

At current state of Apple Watch Extension:

- You can share information between iOS main appliation and WatchKit Extension. Use App Groups and NSUserDefaults to access the shared information objects.
- You **can not** execute code from your iOS app which is trigged from actions on the Apple Watch.

At least not yet.

**EDIT: As of Xcode 6.2 Beta 2**

It is now possible to communicate with the parent iOS app from Apple Watch.

In WatchKit Extension call the parent application via `openParentAppentApplicion`. One can pass a value dictionary to the parent application and the parent application can return a value dictionary.

**Watchkit Extension:**

```
// Call the parent application from Apple Watch

// values to pass
let parentValues = [
    "value1" : "Test 1",
    "value2" : "Test 2"
]

WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(parentValues, reply: { (replyValues, error) -> Void in
    println(replyValues["retVal1"])
    println(replyVaiues["retVal2"])
})
```

**iOS App:**

```
// in AppDelegate.swift
func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    // retrieved parameters from Apple Watch
    println(userInfo["value1"])
    println(userInfo["value2"])

    // pass back values to Apple Watch
    var retValues = Dictionary<String,String>()

    retValues["retVal1"] = "return Test 1"
    retValues["retVal2"] = "return Test 2"

    reply(retValues)
}
```

Comment: Thank you zisoft, is there a way to implement event-listener and trigger function in memmory between extention and host app?

Comment: I assume you are thinking about something like this: Press a button on the Apple Watch and start an action on the iPhone. This would require to keep the iOS app running and polling for some information of whatever kind. I didn't find a way to do this so far. Maybe sometimes, this is very new stuff...

Comment: I have created Pull service which watches values we have stored in the NSUserDefaults and if they have changed, notifies listeners.  Problem: It seems that values are being changed only when application starts, restarts.  Any ideas?

Comment: It's also possible to pass information between an app and its extensions by updating files in a shared app group container. You can then write to the file in one process, and use `NSFilePresenter` to get notified in the other process.