# Can you launch the Apple Watch WK app from iPhone-side code?

Tags: ios, watchkit

WatchKit apps are extensions of iPhone code, however there is Watch-specific logic you can create for behavior of the app extension.

You can open Android Wear apps by passing an Intent from the phone to open a Wear-side Android app, but is there a similar way for the Apple Watch?

When you press a button on the iPhone app, for example, can you open its counterpart app extension on the Watch?

Comment: unable to unerstand your question. Do you need to open phone app from watch??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Watch, WatchKit Extension and main application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190949/apple-watch-watchkit-extension-and-main-application)

Comment: No, I need to open the watch app from the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't open your apple watch app from your iphone. You can only execute background tasks from your apple watch to your iphone using openParentApplication

Comment: Can you use that background task on the Watch to open itself (i.e. the WK application on the Watch)?

Comment: I believe it has the same philosophy has the phone has. You can't force an app to open on the iPhone, so you also can't force an app to open in the watch (either via your iPhone or via the watch itself)